# marty.js ApplicationContainer and Rect Router 1.0.0 beta

Tags: react-router, martyjs

I'm attempting to use Marty v0.10 and React Router v1.0.0. The example React Router provides doesn't seem to allow wrapping a handler in the application container. React Router says to use `React.render` as opposed to `Router.run`. The only example of `Router.run` is on the server side.

My implementation from marty.js v0.10 and React Router v0.13 throws the following error:

`Invariant Violation: Router.run needs a callback`

This is due to `Router.run` now expecting 3 parameters. I'm not sure what the second parameter should be in the browser.

Any tips on getting this:

```
Router.run(routes, (Handler, state) => {
  React.render(
    <ApplicationContainer app={ application }>
      <Handler { ...state.params } />
    </ApplicationContainer>,
    document.body
  );
});
```

to work with Rect Router 1.0.0 beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious question is obvious.

Just throw the render logic into `React.render`.

```
React.render(
  <ApplicationContainer app={ application }>
    { routes }
  </ApplicationContainer>
  , document.body
);
```